# Calculus and Real Analysis: open source lecture notes ready to be edited

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, soft-question, big-list

I would like to collect a big list of good open source lecture notes for a course in

- calculus;
- real analysis.

Such notes should be in `.tex` format, that is, ready to be edited/modified/re-used and compiled using $\LaTeX$.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work, but you might try googling something like "begin{document}" along with some math words that are reasonably specific to the subject matter you want the notes in.

Comment: I've never seen open source lecture notes.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro If your looking for TeX documents, you can use the `filetype` modifier in your Google search, for example: `fractal filetype:tex`.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a page with PDFs of three semesters of calculus notes and also one semester of Real Analysis. Zipped folders titled "source" of $\LaTeX$ code are also available for editing the notes. All free!!

http://www.math.wisc.edu/~angenent/Free-Lecture-Notes/